# Имеется react компонент состоящий из нескольких div

Tags: reactjs

Имеется react компонент состоящий из нескольких div . как узнать на каком именно div произведен click ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете явно передать в обработчик клика какую-нибудь информацию, например айди вашего дива.

```js
clickHandler = (divId) => {
 console.log(divId)
}

render(){
  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this, "1")}>
        div_1
      </div>
      <div onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this, "2")}>
        div_2
      </div>
      <div onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this, "3")}>
        div_3
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Можно, как я показал выше, используя `bind` или, если вы послушаетесь еслинта, то можно так:

```js
<div onClick={() => {this.clickHandler("1")}}>
  div_1
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как и везде - через `e.target`.